# Dovrebbe essere "insistente" invece di "insistito"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, past-participle

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Diamante riuscí a rivedere le torri di Manhattan solo nove mesi dopo la fuga dal campo della Northern Pacific Railway Company. Aveva camminato per duemila miglia. Era salito e sceso da decine di treni merci. Pesava quaranta chili, aveva i capelli rasati a zero, un **insistito** dolore alla schiena e una fame cronica.

Non capisco l'uso che fa l'autrice del participio passato "insistito". Non si dovrebbe dire "un insistente dolore" invece di "un insistito dolore"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dal [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/insistito):

***insistito***:

> 1. p.pass. => insistere
> 2. agg. CO ripetuto con insistenza.

Altri esempi:

Da [*Serpenti nel Paradiso*](https://books.google.it/books?id=a9gwCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT91&dq=%22un%20insistito%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi90aTf1uPkAhVplIsKHeVKBAUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22un%20insistito%22&f=false) di Alicia Giménez-Bartlett, tradotto da Maria Nicola (2013):

> *Un insistito colpo di tosse* di Coronas ci riportò all'ordine. Lasciai passare mezz'ora e poi, in segno di protesta per la perdita di tempo.

Da [*Un sogghigno senza gatto*](https://books.google.it/books?id=DFARxRNP7ZoC&pg=PA108&dq=%22un%20insistito%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi90aTf1uPkAhVplIsKHeVKBAUQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=%22un%20insistito%22&f=false) di Antonio Faeti (1993):

> Ma l'abito che indossa è invece connotato sia da precise allusioni a nuove tendenze (la gonna ampia, per esempio) *sia da un insistito riecheggiare di consolidati*, anche se non certo molto antichi, «archetipi».

L’uso di “insistito” come aggettivo è più  letterario e meno comune   di "insistente".

Comment: Tuttavia, la marca d'uso "CO" [significa](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6): «comune; sono così marcati i vocaboli che sono usati e compresi indipendentemente dalla professione o mestiere che si esercita o dalla collocazione regionale e che sono generalmente noti a chiunque abbia un livello mediosuperiore di istruzione».

Comment: @Charo - sì, ma questo non significa che sia di uso comune come insistente, ad esempio.

Comment: Se citi un autore straniero, come in questo caso la Giménez-Bartlett, dovresti citare anche il traduttore, sia per correttezza sia perché è lui o lei che ha scelto di usare la parola “insistito”.